# How to make compilation different between Debug against Release?

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, release

I'm a newbee to C#, and encounter a problem when compiling a C# project. It's about debug log in Debug and Release modes.
I want the log function to be called in Debug mode, but not called in Release mode, taking performance into account.
I know in C/C++, this is easy to be done:

```
// this is C/C++ sample, not C#
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugLog(CString,__VA_ARGS__) LogFunction(CString,__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugLog
#endif
```

In the above C/C++ code, the DebugLog() is compiled and called in Debug mode, but not compiled or called in Release mode, so the performance can be ensured.

Is there anyway in C# that works like the above C/C++ codes?

Comment: Perhaps you could take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The equivalent is the [Conditional] attribute on a method.  Like this:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void DebugLog(string fmt, params object[] args) {
    // etc..
}
```

In the Release build (with DEBUG not defined), both the method and the calls to the method are removed by the compiler.  Before you re-invent this wheel, be sure to review the Debug and Trace classes in the .NET framework, they already do this.  And have lots of flexibility to redirect the debug/trace info.

Comment: Thanks for answers from all of you guys. I think this is what I want - even not compiled in Debug mode.

Comment: This only works if the method's return type is void.  So you can't decorate an MVC Action like that.  I ended up using `#if DEBUG`

Answer (score 20):

In C# you can do

```
#if DEBUG
                //debug-mode only snippet go here.
#endif
```

Here's the [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) for the `#if` directive.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the same thing in C#.  In the project properties, you can set a conditional compilation symbol like `DEBUG`.  In fact, I think Visual Studio will do this by default when you create a project - it will add a `DEBUG` flag when the project is in Debug mode, and remove the flag when you switch to Release mode.  This can be configured in the Project Properties->Build tab.  You can also add your own flags for things like platform-specific code.  The `Pocket_PC` flag was a famous one for doing old-school Windows Mobile development on the .NET Compact Framework.

With this, you can add the pre-processor directives like this:

```
#if DEBUG

//  debug code here

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Other methodology, can include a "Conditional" attribute like

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
void DebugLog()
{
   // method code here
}
```

More informations can be found [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xssyw96.aspx#Y573)

Comment: Thanks for answers from all of you guys. I think this is what I want - not compiled in Debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>Function to Set Debug Flag to true if DEBUG is in Effect</summary>
/// <param name="theDebugFlag">output - true if DEBUG, unchanged if RELEASE</param>
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
static void QueryDebugStatus(ref Boolean theDebugFlag)
{
theDebugFlag = true;
}
```